# Insufficient memory in Nonlinear Model Fit with ParametricNDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, fitting, nonlinear

I try to fit parameters to ODE solver with chemical kinetic eqations:

```
R = 8.31; (* gas constant *)

(* inital contrations *)
c[v0_, T_, totalGasFlow_] := v0/totalGasFlow*101325/(R*T);
c0n2o = c[1.5, 298, 52];   
c0n2 = c[0, 298, 55];
c0o2 = c[0, 298, 52];

(* rate constants for reactions *)
calckarr[T_, nu_, eAct_] := 
 nu*Exp[-(eAct)/(R*T)]

kActFor[T_, a1f_] := calckarr[T, a1f, 111930];
kadsO2[T_, a3_] := calckarr[T, a3, 103246];
kdesO2[T_, a2_] := calckarr[T, a2, 117720];

(* rate equations of reactions*)
r1f[T_, a1f_] := kActFor[T, a1f]* cn2o[t]*(1 - theta[t]);
r2[T_, a2_] := kdesO2[T, a2]*(theta[t])^2;
r3[T_, a3_] := kadsO2[T, a3]*co2[t]*(1 - theta[t]);

(*rate of reactions for specific compounds *)
rtheta[T_, a1f_, a2_, a3_] := r1f[T, a1f] - 2 r2[T, a2] + 2 r3[T, a3];
rn2[T_, a1f_] := r1f[T, a1f]
rn2o[T_, a1f_] := -r1f[T, a1f]
ro2[T_, a2_, a3_] := r2[T, a2] - r3[T, a3]

(* ODE solver *)
sol[T_, a1f_, a2_, a3_] := NDSolve[
  {theta'[t] == rtheta[T, a1f, a2, a3],
   cn2'[t] == rn2[T, a1f],
   cn2o'[t] ==  rn2o[T, a1f],
   co2'[t] == ro2[T, a2, a3],
   theta[0] == 0,
   cn2[0] == c0n2,
   cn2o[0] == c0n2o,
   co2[0] == c0o2}, {cn2, cn2o, co2, theta}, {t, 10^-6, 3}]

(* experimental data *)
data={{374.15, 0.000627806}, {382.95, 0.00441}, {396.45, 0.00583}, {414.25,
   0.0061}, {433.35, 0.00821}, {451.95, 0.01279}, {470.15, 
  0.01131}, {488.05, 0.01178}, {507.15, 0.0122}, {526.65, 
  0.01351}, {546.35, 0.01393}, {566.05, 0.02557}, {586.45, 
  0.03422}, {606.45, 0.05179}, {626.75, 0.08718}, {647.05, 
  0.14891}, {664.75, 0.24017}, {682.75, 0.35589}, {700.05, 
  0.48896}, {717.15, 0.6169}, {734.55, 0.72361}, {750.95, 
  0.80726}, {765.55, 0.86888}, {781.45, 0.91729}, {797.25, 
  0.95264}, {812.55, 0.97429}}
```

I manipulated `a1f`, `a2` and `a3` to find first shots of values:

```
temps = Table[T, {T, 400, 800, 10}];
Manipulate[
 Show[ListPlot@data,
  ListLinePlot[
   Transpose@{temps, Table[
       (c0n2o - cn2o[0.4])/c0n2o /. sol[T, 10^a1f, 10^a2, 10^a3], {T, 
        temps}] // Flatten}, PlotStyle -> Red]],
 {{a1f,8.72}, 6, 14}, {{a2,10.9}, 6, 12}, {{a3,11.03}, 6, 12}]
```

[image]

So, the next step is fine-tuning and searching for perfect values with `NonlinearModelFit` and `ParametricNDSolve`:

```
conv = ParametricNDSolveValue[
  {theta'[t] == rtheta[T, a1f, a2, a3],
   cn2'[t] == rn2[T, a1f],
   cn2o'[t] ==  rn2o[T, a1f],
   co2'[t] == ro2[T, a2, a3],
   theta[0] == 0,
   cn2[0] == c0n2,
   cn2o[0] == c0n2o,
   co2[0] == c0o2},
 (c0n2o- cn2o[0.4])/c0n2o,
  {t, 10^-6, 3},
  {T, a1f, a2, a3}]
```

When I plot `conv` with parameters from `Manipulate` it works perfectly:

```
Show[Plot[conv[T, 10^8.72, 10^10.9, 10^11.03], {T, 400, 800}, 
  PlotStyle -> Red, PlotLegends -> {"model"}], 
 ListPlot[data, PlotLegends -> {"experimental data"}]]
```

[image]

But when I try to fit these values, even only for 1 parameter, it crashes:

```
fit = NonlinearModelFit[data, conv[T, a1f, 10^10.9, 10^11.03], a1f, T]


(* 
General::nomem: The current computation was aborted because there was insufficient memory available to complete the computation. 
OR
General::ovfl: Overflow occurred in computation. *)
```

Of course, memory is not the issue, I have 16GB of RAM and it fails after 2s of computations. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: When I run your code, the error that I get is `InterpolatingFunction::dmval: Input value {0.4} lies outside the range of data in the interpolating function. Extrapolation will be used.` In other words, it seems like `NonlinearModelFit` is searching outside the region of the interpolating function, and since interpolating functions are polynomials, they will blow up, sometimes quite rapidly, outside of the region on which the fit is made.  I suspect that this is the problem. (My kernel also quits when I run your code.) A fix might be to add some constraints in `NonlinearModelFit`. Let me check.

Comment: I can't seem to make anything work. I think there just might be an issue with trying to use a `ParametricFunction`, which amounts to an `InterpolatingFunction` once values have been entered, as the functional form in `NonlinearModelFit`.

Comment: The extrapolation problem is known for me, it happens often with numerical calculations with differential equations. Still, `NonlinearModelFit` should reject values which blows the polynomials and start to search for the nearest place when it doesnt't crash. Maybe it is a problem which algorithm to use in such a situation. A simplier example of working fitting were solved by @MarcoB in this thread:  [link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/270195/change-domain-of-kinetic-functions-in-order-to-fit-with-parametricndsolve) This question is just continuation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `FindFit` and `Method -> NMinimize` can find all of the `{a1f, a2, a3}`.

```
sol = FindFit[data, conv[T, a1f, a2, a3], {a1f, a2, a3}, T, 
  Method -> NMinimize]
Show[ListPlot[data], 
 Plot[conv[T, a1f, a2, a3] /. sol, {T, 0, 1000}, PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image]

- `Method -> "NMinimize"` in `NonlinearModelFit` also work.

```
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, conv[T, a1f, a2, a3], {a1f, a2, a3}, T, 
  Method -> "NMinimize"]
Show[ListPlot[data], Plot[nlm[T], {T, 0, 1000}, PlotStyle -> Red]]
nlm["BestFitParameters"]
```

The same as `FindFit`.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Wow, so simple, and works fantastic! Thank You for your help.

Answer (score 2):

```
$Version

(* "13.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

R = 831/100; (*gas constant*)

(*initial contrations*)
c[v0_, T_, totalGasFlow_] := v0/totalGasFlow*101325/(R*T);
c0n2o = c[3/2, 298, 52];
c0n2 = c[0, 298, 55];
c0o2 = c[0, 298, 52];

(*rate constants for reactions*)
calckarr[T_, nu_, eAct_] := nu*Exp[-(eAct)/(R*T)]

kActFor[T_, a1f_] := calckarr[T, a1f, 111930]
kadsO2[T_, a3_] := calckarr[T, a3, 103246]
kdesO2[T_, a2_] := calckarr[T, a2, 117720]

(*rate equations of reactions*)
r1f[T_, a1f_] := kActFor[T, a1f]*cn2o[t]*(1 - theta[t]);
r2[T_, a2_] := kdesO2[T, a2]*(theta[t])^2;
r3[T_, a3_] := kadsO2[T, a3]*co2[t]*(1 - theta[t]);

(*rate of reactions for specific compounds*)
rtheta[T_, a1f_, a2_, a3_] := 
  r1f[T, a1f] - 2 r2[T, a2] + 2 r3[T, a3];
rn2[T_, a1f_] := r1f[T, a1f]
rn2o[T_, a1f_] := -r1f[T, a1f]
ro2[T_, a2_, a3_] := r2[T, a2] - r3[T, a3]

(*experimental data*)
data = {
    {374.15, 0.000627806}, {382.95, 0.00441}, {396.45, 
     0.00583}, {414.25, 0.0061},
    {433.35, 0.00821}, {451.95, 0.01279},
    {470.15, 0.01131}, {488.05, 0.01178},
    {507.15, 0.0122}, {526.65, 0.01351},
    {546.35, 0.01393}, {566.05, 0.02557},
    {586.45, 0.03422}, {606.45, 0.05179},
    {626.75, 0.08718}, {647.05, 0.14891},
    {664.75, 0.24017}, {682.75, 0.35589},
    {700.05, 0.48896}, {717.15, 0.6169},
    {734.55, 0.72361}, {750.95, 0.80726},
    {765.55, 0.86888}, {781.45, 0.91729},
    {797.25, 0.95264}, {812.55, 0.97429}} //
   Rationalize[#, 0] &;
```

For `ParametricNDSolve` use

```
conv = ParametricNDSolve[{theta'[t] == rtheta[T, a1f, a2, a3], 
    cn2'[t] == rn2[T, a1f], cn2o'[t] == rn2o[T, a1f], 
    co2'[t] == ro2[T, a2, a3], theta[0] == 0, cn2[0] == c0n2, 
    cn2o[0] == c0n2o, co2[0] == c0o2}, {cn2, cn2o, co2, theta}, {t, 
    10^-6, 3}, {T, a1f, a2, a3}, WorkingPrecision -> 12];

(fit = NonlinearModelFit[data,
    (c0n2o - cn2o[T, a1f, 10^(109/10), 10^(1103/100)][
         2/5] /. conv)/c0n2o, a1f, T,
    WorkingPrecision -> 12])["BestFitParameters"]

(* NonlinearModelFit::sszero: The step size in the search has become less than the tolerance prescribed by the PrecisionGoal option, but the gradient is larger than the tolerance specified by the AccuracyGoal option. There is a possibility that the method has stalled at a point that is not a local minimum. *)

(* {a1f -> 5.54350617598*10^8} *)
```

Despite the warning,

```
Show[
 Plot[fit[T], {T, 400, 800},
  PlotStyle -> Red,
  PlotLegends -> {"model"}],
 ListPlot[data,
  PlotLegends -> {"experimental\ndata"}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for Your help. For unknow reason, it doesn't work for me, maybe because of different version? I work on 12.1.1, Windows 10. The evaluation of the code takes more than minute for one variable. However, @cvgmt answer below works pretty well.

Comment: Works with version `12.1.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2020)` The `AbsoluteTiming` for the plots was just under 22 seconds.